# MONUSCO: Member state reaction to UN offensive in the Congo

Tags: international-law, united-nations, africa

Last week [in the DROC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-42285871) the UN suffered its greatest loss of peacekeeper life since [the Battle of Mogadishu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mogadishu_(1993)#U.S._and_UNOSOM), with at least 15 Tanzanian peacekeepers being killed by the insurgent group [Allied Democratic Forces (ADF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied_Democratic_Forces).

In reading about this I came across the unique mandate of [MONUSCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MONUSCO#Organization) - the UN mission in the DROC - that enables them to pursue [unilateral, unprovoked offensive actions](https://www.un.org/press/en/2013/sc10964.doc.htm) which seems to violate, in spirit if not in letter, the [Third Principle of Peacekeeping](https://peacekeeping.un.org/en/principles-of-peacekeeping) as put forth by the UN.

My questions is: Have member states of the UN voiced any reaction to this sort of operation? Not necessarily just this one, but I am unaware of a similar example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change from purely peace keeping to [peace enforcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_enforcement) was [authorized](https://www.un.org/apps/news/story.asp?NewsID=44523#.Wi8K8fZrxKt) by the UN security council at the [request](https://www.un.org/sg/en/content/sg/statement/2013-03-28/statement-attributable-spokesperson-secretary-general-adoption-new) of the secretary general in 2013.

Various steps along the way have been met with some resistance, specifically the use of [drone reconnaissance](https://www.news24.com/Africa/News/Rwanda-opposes-use-of-drones-DRC-20130109) but mostly countries agree that the conflict is a problem.

I don't think there are any similar examples.